# Inserting large number of data rows into cloudsql table via PyMySql from .csv

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, google-cloud-sql, pymysql

I am new to CloudSQL & I am trying to insert records of 40+ different columns and over 1.5 million rows. However I am unable to do this in Google CloudSQL. I have taken quite a number of measures listed below to resolve this issue but the main error that I get is:

```
ERROR:
textPayload:  "2019-04-12T06:10:47.348295Z 8554 [Note] Aborted connection 8554 to db: 'xxxxx_xxx' user: 'root' host: 'x.x.x.x' (Got an error reading communication packets)"
```

Summary:

1. I am using Python, `PyMySql` to insert 1.5 million rows of data into a table of 35 columns
2. Instance, DB, Table have already been created in CloudSQL.
3. System configuration: vCPUs - 4, Memory- 15 GB, SSD storage - 10 GB
4. I can load this data completely fine in my local system.
5. In Google CloudSQl, deployment time is extremely long and deployment is Successful.
6. But when I check my table, it is empty.
7. The `MySql` error logs in the instance shows the above.

I have made tried the following actions:

- Using `API URL`/ `.txt` / `.json` file for upload instead now using `.csv`.
- Thinking it is a system issue, I upgraded the system from 8GB Memory to 15 GB Memory.
- Thinking that SQL default configs are causing limitations, I have added the following:

  - sql_mode : MAXDB,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER
  - max_allowed_packet: 1073741824
  - net_read_timeout: 4294967295
  - wait_timeout: 31536000
- Inserted lesser number of rows, max rows able to insert = 100

```py
def adddata():
    try:
        conn = pymysql.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + 'karto-235001:asia-east1:karto', user='xxx', password='xxx', db='xxx')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        insert_ = "INSERT INTO data_table(a, b, c) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
        with open('info.csv', newline='') as myFile:
            reader = csv.reader(myFile)
            for item in reader:
                cur.execute(insert_, (item[3], item[4], item[5]))
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

I have checked online and have implemented the recommended solutions by CloudSQL and other stack-overflow users. If anyone could identify what I am doing wrong or if there are issues with my code or configuration? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you want to upload information contained in a CSV file using Python. Have you tried importing directly to the database? You can  follow the steps in the link[1].

In the meantime I’ll try to replicate your case.  You also may want to check if your installations and configuration are correct.

Verify if Your Cloud SQL instance and connection [2] and you Python installation[3].

```
[1]https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#csv
[2]https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine
[3]https://cloud.google.com/python/setup
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Your suggestiong to import directly to db worked for me! Thank you!